# How do you make mobile web apps like Trello did?

Tags: iphone, web-applications, iphone-standalone-web-app

When I go to [Trello](http://Trello.com) on my iPhone and bookmark it to my home screen then go into the link from the home screen, it doesn't open the link in Safari, but in a new app. How is that done?

Comment: Sorry, I figured this was the best spot since I felt it was programming related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

in your `<head>` block.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS it's called a Web Clip. Have a look at this documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

And here's a JavaScript library that will do a nice little "add to home screen" popover: http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen